# to create a new column and give max value as True and remaing False from the given duplicate dataframe

Tags: pandas

```
index   Key_words_x           Similarity    Label
0   0   embarker               0.996412 INVESTMENT
1   1   embarkest              0.996413 INVESTMENT
2   2   embarketh              0.996418 INVESTMENT
3   3   negative gearing       0.996215 INVESTMENT
4   4   overfinance            0.996215 INVESTMENT
... ... ... ... ...
7521 7521   crowded            0.340883 LOCATION
7522 7522   nanjing            0.337241 LOCATION
7523 7523   vibrant            0.336480 LOCATION
7524 7524   sprawl             0.335916 LOCATION
7525 7525   flourishing        0.333760 LOCATION
```

ands the output should be ..
here Which one has max similarity as None and remaing less similarities as False

```
index   Key_words_x           Similarity    Label      Result
0   0   embarker               0.996412 INVESTMENT
1   1   embarkest              0.996413 INVESTMENT     
2   2   embarketh              0.996418 INVESTMENT     True
3   3   negative gearing       0.996215 INVESTMENT
4   4   overfinance            0.996215 INVESTMENT
... ... ... ... ...
7521 7521   crowded            0.340883 LOCATION
7522 7522   nanjing            0.337241 LOCATION
7523 7523   vibrant            0.336480 LOCATION
7524 7524   sprawl             0.335916 LOCATION
7525 7525   flourishing        0.333760 LOCATION
```

Comment: please format your question

Comment: Warm welcome to SO! Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. Then update your question to help us to help you. Your question is to broad, missing code and not using correct upper case letters. A sentence starts with an upper case letter.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you can transform with the max per group (assuming here per label), then compare each value to the group max:

```
m = df.groupby('Label')['Similarity'].transform('max')

df['Result'] = df['Similarity'].eq(m)
```

output:

```
      index       Key_words_x  Similarity       Label  Result
0         0          embarker    0.996412  INVESTMENT   False
1         1         embarkest    0.996413  INVESTMENT   False
2         2         embarketh    0.996418  INVESTMENT    True
3         3  negative gearing    0.996215  INVESTMENT   False
4         4       overfinance    0.996215  INVESTMENT   False
7521   7521           crowded    0.340883    LOCATION    True
7522   7522           nanjing    0.337241    LOCATION   False
7523   7523           vibrant    0.336480    LOCATION   False
7524   7524            sprawl    0.335916    LOCATION   False
7525   7525       flourishing    0.333760    LOCATION   False
```

Comment: i have a duplicate values dataframe from those duplicate values which one having  high values as True remaing all False